# Calculating list of areas between the curves in an intersection region

Tags: regions, intersection

I have 2 tables;

**table 1:**

```
ctr = {(Exp[Pi*0.5] + 1)/2, 0};
radius = (Exp[Pi*0.5] - 1)/2;
pp = PolarPlot[
  Evaluate@Table[Exp[(t + 2*Pi*i/120)*0.5], {i, 1, 120}], {t, -Pi, 
   Pi}, RegionFunction -> (Norm[{#, #2} - ctr] <= radius &)]
Total[ArcLength /@ Cases[pp, _Line, All]]
```

[image: spiral]

and **table 2:**

```
ctr = {(Exp[Pi*0.5] - 1)/2, 0};
radius = (Exp[Pi*0.5] - 1)/2;
pp2 = ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[Table[{t, t (Tan[2 j Pi / 120])}, {j, 1, 60}]], {t, -5, 5},
   RegionFunction -> (Norm[{#, #2} - ctr] <= radius &), 
  PlotRange -> All]
Total[ArcLength /@ Cases[pp2, _Line, All]]
```

[image: Line]

I want to calculate each area between the curves and show them in histogram so I can evaluate maximum and minimum gaps between the tables. I illustrated what I want as below:

[image: gradient]

can you show me how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could define a `ParametricRegion` , examplary between curves #10 and #11

```
reg10 = ParametricRegion[{{Cos[t], Sin[t]} Exp[(t + 2*Pi*ii/120)/2], (Sqrt[#.#] < radius) &[{Cos[t],Sin[t]} Exp[(t + 2*Pi*ii/120)/2] - ctr]}
, {{t, -Pi, Pi}, {ii, 10, 11}}]
DiscretizeRegion[reg10]
```

[image]

```
Area[DiscretizeRegion[reg10]]
(*0.0592725*)
```

**addendum**

Knowing the plot `pp` a very fast straightforward solution is possible:
First get the Line-objects from the plot

```
linien = Cases[pp, _Line , Infinity];
```

Two neighboring lines form a polygon from which the area can be calculated

```
areas=Table[ Area@Polygon[Join[linien[[i]][[1]], Reverse[linien[[i + 1]][[1]]]]], {i,1, Length[linien] - 1}] 
(*{0.0243947, 0.0281509, 0.0318023, 0.0353948, 0.039143, 0.0430014, \
0.0469289, 0.050997, 0.0551564, 0.0594015, 0.0639209, 0.0684968, \
0.0731468, 0.0780328, 0.0830698, 0.0882845, 0.0936695, 0.0992263, \
0.104955, 0.111007, 0.117283, 0.123424, 0.129694, 0.136315, 0.143126, \
0.150108, 0.157259, 0.164582, 0.172953, 0.1806, 0.187462, 0.195366, \
0.203387, 0.21151, 0.22005, 0.228322, 0.23627, 0.24457, 0.252866, \
0.261078, 0.269163, 0.27711, 0.284845, 0.292302, 0.299405, 0.306072, \
0.312203, 0.317686, 0.322383, 0.326143, 0.329235, 0.330515, 0.329747, \
0.327478, 0.322887, 0.315273, 0.304139, 0.288177, 0.265912, 0.234501, \
0.187173}*)
```

That's it! Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, how could I store each of the ares into a table so I can show the histogram could you help me with that as well?

Comment: Put it in a Table[...,{i,1,119}]

Comment: @ Alper91 Look at the edit of my answer, I added a solution which only needs to know `pp`

Comment: Thanks. It worked easily.